# Send Array with unrest and objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, unirest

I am working in a small project in IOS which send a json message with [unirest](http://unirest.io) lib. The request contains an array that It gives error and I don't know why.

This is the code:

```
NSMutableDictionary * parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *valueMd5 = @"examplemd5file";
[parameters setValue:valueMd5 forKey:@"md5file"];
NSString *path = @"pathfile";
[parameters setValue:path forKey:@"path"];

float latitude = 1.0f;
NSString *strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latitude];
[parameters setValue:strLatitude forKey:@"latitude"];

float longitude = 1.0f;
NSString *strLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitude];
[parameters setValue:strLongitude forKey:@"longitude"];

int image_width = 100;
NSString *strImageWidth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", image_width];
[parameters setValue:strImageWidth forKey:@"image_width"];

int image_height = 100;
NSString *strImageHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", image_height];
[parameters setValue:strImageHeight forKey:@"image_height"];

//"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
NSString *data_taken = @"11-12-1111 12:12:12";
[parameters setValue:data_taken forKey:@"data_taken"];

NSArray *tags  = @[@"tag1", @"tag2"];
  //   tags = @[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tag1", @"tag2"];
[parameters setValue:tags forKey:@"tags"];


NSString* iaError = @"Error description";
[parameters setValue:iaError forKey:@"iaError"];


NSString *token = @"5aecf374c3dc09.43880964";
NSString* complete_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/batch/metadata/%@", URL_BASE, token];

[[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
    [request setUrl:complete_url];
    [request setHeaders:headers];
    [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
    // This is the asyncronous callback block

    NSInteger code = response.code;
    NSDictionary *responseHeaders = response.headers;
    UNIJsonNode *body = response.body;
    NSData *rawBody = response.rawBody;

}];
```

And this is the error:

> 2018-05-08 18:09:28.063517+0200 tflite_simple_example[6600:187624]
>   -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000238220 2018-05-08 18:09:28.073351+0200 
>   tflite_simple_example[6600:187624] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000238220'

Comment: HTTP Headers should be a `Dictionary` which keys are `NSString` objects, and values are `NSString` objects too. See `allHTTPHeaderFields` and `valueForHTTPHeaderField:` methods of `NSURLRequest`. I don't know UNIRest, but it wouldn't surprise that it use `NS(Mutable)URLRequest` and that's could be the cause of your issue. I don't know the documentation of your API, but maybe `NSString *tags = [@[@"tag1", @"tag2"] componentsJoindsByString:@","]` Or at least tell us what it should look like?

Comment: I could fix it with this... I only needed to add json array in the dictionary. If you want to include as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `NSURLRequest` that I guess `UNIRest` use in background (or use a similar approach), HTTPHeaders fields are `NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *>`: `NSDictionary` where keys are `NSString` and where values are `NSString`.

See the corresponding methods/properties of `NSURLRequest` or `NSMutableURLRequest`.

```
@property(readonly, copy) NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *> *allHTTPHeaderFields;
- (NSString *)valueForHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field;
- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field;
- (void)addValue:(NSString *)value 
forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field;
```

So you can't put a `NSArray` object as a value. iOS expects a NSString, and that explain that you get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000238220'

There, we recognize that the method called is `length` (`NSString` basic one in Objective-C) trying to be called on a `NSArray` object and not a `NSString` one. Since `NSArray` doesn't implement it, that's causing that error and crash.
What may be hard to tell the reason is because it's an inner hidden code of Cocoa that call `length` (you don't see it yourself). But knowing where, and assuming that `length` is for a `NSString` object, and that the culprit is also a `NSArray` object help you pinpoint the issue:

```
NSArray *tags  = @[@"tag1", @"tag2"];
[parameters setValue:tags forKey:@"tags"];
```

So `tags` needs to be a `NSString` object and not a `NSArray` one. 
According to you, the API needs to be called using a JSON Stringified.
So:

```
NSArray *tags = @[@"tag1", @"tag2"];
NSData *tagsJSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tags options:0 error:nil]; //Might be useful to use a `NSError` object just in case
NSString *tagsJSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tagsJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[parameters setValue:tags forKey:@"tags"];
```

As I supposed in comments, if your API needed the tags with comma separated:

```
NSArray *tags = @[@"tag1", @"tag2"];
NSString *tagsString = [tags componentsJoinedByString:@","];
[parameters setValue:tags forKey:@"tags"];
```